# Google indexing : _escaped_fragment_ not working for home page

Tags: ajax, gwt

I did setup my website (GWT) to be crawlable by Google. While using the "fetch as google" page on the Google webmastertool, I see the following pattern :

- Accessing "http://www.mysite.com/#!AJAX_URL" is correctly redirected
  to the snapshot
- But Google does not request the snapshot for "http://www.mysite.com"
  although I did set the  in the
  web.xml

==> Two questions related to this :

- Is it because the Google webmaster tool is not clever enough but the real robot will correctly request the snapshot
- Should I add something in the web.xml or anywhere else ?

Thanks,

Hugues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found the answer.  It's just the Fetch as Googlebot feature that doesn't check for meta-tags, and instead just returns the raw content. When Google crawls and index the pages, they will notice the meta-tag and act accordingly.

The link to the answer is here (see comment of [JohnMu](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/bZgWCJTnl08)) :

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 'robots.txt' allows crawler access:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Also, you may want to submit a [Sitemap to Webmaster Tools](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183669).

It sounds like the snapshots are being served correctly. Just in case, I post the relevant parts of a working 'index.php'. The static pages are located in 'static/${TOKEN}.html'

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

function static_url ($token) { return 'static/' . $token . '.html'; }

$escaped_fragment = $_GET['_escaped_fragment_'];

if (isset($escaped_fragment)) {
  $fragment = preg_replace('/\//', '', $escaped_fragment);
  $file = static_url($fragment);

  if($escaped_fragment == '' || $escaped_fragment == '/'
      || (! file_exists($file))) {
    $fragment = '${DEFAULT_PLACE}:${DEFAULT_STATE}'; // your default place
    $file = static_url($fragment);
  }
  $re = '/(^<[^>]*>)|(\n|\r\n|\t|\s{2,4})*/';

  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
  if ($handle != false) {
    $content = preg_replace($re, '', fread($handle, filesize($file)));
    fclose($handle);
  }
  else {
    $content = 'Page not found!';
    header(php_sapi_name() == 'cgi' ? 'Status: 404' : 'HTTP/1.1 404');
  }
  echo $content;
} else { ?>

<html> ... Your GWT host page ... </html>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your feedback. Tried what you proposed but that did not work. As you will see in the answer to my own question, it is the "fetch as googlebot" feature that doesn't check for meta-tags.